# Ubuntu Touch versions?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, versions

I understand Ubuntu Touch has different versions. Do they correspond to the regular desktop/server versions, i.e., will there be an Ubuntu Touch 15.04 next week too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ubuntu Touch has the same version numbers.

Comment: So Touch will be released on April 23 along with the others?

Comment: @user78162 Should be.

Comment: No, some weeks later, as was published on insights.ubuntu.com (though I cannot find the link).